# Problem meshing hexahedron

Tags: finite-element-method, mesh

I have observed the following problem when meshing with the Hexahedra function. A rectangular body can be meshed by ToElementMesh and ToBoundaryMesh. A non-rectangular solid cannot. The difference between pts1 and pts2 is the last entry. What could be the problem here?
Do you have any idea? Thanks in advances.

```
<< NDSolve`FEM`;
<< NDSolve`FEM`;
nx = 3;
ny = 1;
nz = 0.2;

pts1 = {{-nx/2, -ny/2, -nz/2}, {nx/2, -ny/2, -nz/2}, {nx/2, 
    ny/2, -nz/2}, {-nx/2, ny/2, -nz/2},
   {-nx/2, -ny/2, 0.5*nz}, {nx/2, -ny/2, 0.5*nz}, {nx/2, ny/2, 
    0.5 nz}, {-nx/2, ny/2, 0.5*nz}};

pts2 = {{-nx/2, -ny/2, -nz/2}, {nx/2, -ny/2, -nz/2}, {nx/2, 
    ny/2, -nz/2}, {-nx/2, ny/2, -nz/2},
   {-nx/2, -ny/2, 0.5*nz}, {nx/2, -ny/2, 0.5*nz}, {nx/2, ny/2, 
    0.5 nz}, {-nx/2, ny/2, 0.6*nz}};

"Graphics of rectangular Hex"
Graphics3D[Hexahedron[pts1]]
"Graphics of non-rectangular Hex"
Graphics3D[Hexahedron[pts2]]

bMesh1 = ToBoundaryMesh[Hexahedron[pts1], "MeshOrder" -> 1];
bMesh2 = ToBoundaryMesh[Hexahedron[pts2], "MeshOrder" -> 1];

"Wireframe of rectangular Hex"
bMesh1["Wireframe"]
"Wireframe of non-rectangular Hex"
bMesh2["Wireframe"]
```

[image]

Comment: Slightly simpler example of the problem: https://pastebin.com/csn4KPFf also shows it's not a machine precision issue, but even fails with exact rational coordinates. `SurfaceArea` also fails on the non-rectangular version, but works on the rectangular one.

Comment: I think some faces of the second Hex are not coplanar.

Comment: Do you think there is a way to eliminate this error?

Comment: You could triangulate the surface. Btw. If you want me to note your comments you'd have to use the @ plus my user name. I did not see your comment until now.